# The operating system on this computer or its service pack level does not meet the minimum requirments for SQL Server 2014

Tags: uninstallation, sql-server-2014

when i am trying to uninstall SQL Server 2014, getting error as listed below

**The operating system on this computer or its service pack level does not meet the minimum requirments for SQL Server 2014. to determine the minimum required operating system supported for this Sql Server release, see hardware and software requirments for installing Sql Server 2014.**

why is it checking Operating system require for installation while i am trying to uninstall the product.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Your post helped me . +1 for that. :)

Answer (score 7):

Launch setup.exe from an elevated command shell. Change to the directory "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2014", then type:

```
Setup.exe /action=uninstall
```

Comment: If the setup.exe is not there, try using the `Program Files (x86)` folder.

Comment: Hi Thanks Men, Even I ran into this problem. this worked for me. :)

Comment: When the directory does not exist because that version of SQL Server has not been installed?  OK, so I use the folder into which SQL Express installation files were extracted instead. I run you command from the command line (launched as Administrator).  I see the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this will help someone.

For SQL server 2016, it didn't work for me even with the setup.exe. We have to uninstall SQL Server Management Studio entry from Control Panel as suggested in link below

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2751936